# Manipulating a RecordArray

Tags: ember.js, ember-data

I have a RecordArray that has come back from a App.ModelName.find().

I'd like to do some things with it, like:

- paginating through the set of records within
- adding records from another findQuery into the array

I may be confused, but it seems like it's difficult (or at least undocumented) on how to work with the records that come back from find()/findAll()/findQuery() other than looping over the set and displaying them as normal.

This is further complicated by the array that gets returned from all(), which seems to be closer to an identity map, maybe.

None of this may be possible, but if it isn't I can open issues and start to work on that myself.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `RecordArray`s returned by Ember Data aren't really meant for modification. In particular, `Model.find()` (sans-argument) and `Model.all()` return live arrays that keep updating as new matching records are available.

If you want to manipulate an array of models, you're best off using `Model.find({})`(the argument makes it use `findQuery()`) and observing the `isLoaded` property. Something like this:

```
query: null,

init: function() {
  // should really do this in the route
  this.set('query', Model.find({}));
},

content: function() {
  var query = this.get('query');
  return query && query.get('isLoaded') ? query.toArray() : [];
}.property('query.isLoaded')
```

Now content returns a plain old array and you can have your way with it (though you still need to wait for the records to load before you can start modifying the array).

If the issue is that you want a query to keep updating, then consider using `Model.filter()`, which returns a live array like `find()`, but accepts a matching function. Note that confusingly, but quite intentionally, none of `find()`, `all()`, and `filter()` have an `isLoaded` property.

As for pagination, you could try [a simple mixin approach](https://gist.github.com/tchak/1559628), or a more elaborate [rails-based solution](https://github.com/mathieul/page_wrapper).

Comment: Model.filter() ended up being what I wanted. I keep my own list of filters and I've started to build an abstraction on top of it so I can filter on multiple properties and things.

Thank you for your detailed reply.