# Ember.JS - 'TypeError: internalModel.getRecord is not a function' when trying to reverse a collection of records

Tags: ember.js, promise, ember-data, ember-cli, ember-cli-mirage

--Using Ember Data 2.7.1--

I am trying to reverse the order of a collection of records without first turning them into an array using toArray(). This collection of objects comes from the promise returned by this.store.findAll('history-item').

I want to do this the ember way instead of making them plain javascript. I am getting a TypeError: internalModel.getRecord coming from record-array.js. For some reason when it is trying to do objectAtContent(), the content it is looking seems to not have a type. Through the stack trace I can see that the object I am dealing with is [Class], class being the history-item model. A few stack calls before the objectAtContent(), the object being dealt with switches from that history-item model to some other Class object that has no type attribute.

I am able to use Ember Inspector to see my data correctly, and if I just displayed the original collection of records on my template, it shows properly.

Has anyone run into this?

Some thoughts and considerations:

-Is there anything special about how findAll() works with its promise that doesn't allow for reversal since it is reloading in the background? I do want it to keep reloading live data.

-I am using ember-cli-mirage to mock my db and endpoints and I've follow the instructions to the letter I think. I am using an unconfigured JSONAPISerializer for mirage and and a unconfigured JSONAPIAdapter for ember. Could it have anything to do with metadata that is being sent from the back? Could it have something to with the models or records not being set up? Is there something special I have to do?

Route Segment that defines model and tries to reverse it:
[note: I know it may not be convention to prep the data (ordering) in the route but I just put it in here for ease of description. I usually do it outside in the controller or component]

```
  model(){
    return this.get('store').findAll('history-item').then(function(items){
      return items.reverseObjects();
    }).catch(failure);
```

History list model declaration:

```
  export default DS.Model.extend({
    question: DS.attr('string'),
    answer: DS.attr('string')
  });
```

Ember-Cli-Mirage config.js end points:

```
  this.get('/history-items', (schema) => {
     return schema.historyItems.all();
  });
```

Ember-Cli-Mirage fixture for history-items:

```
  export default [
    {id: 1, question: "1is this working?", answer: "Of course!"}
  }
```

Error:

```
  TypeError: internalModel.getRecord coming from record-array.js
```

This issue also happens when I try to create a save a record. The save is successful but when the model gets reloaded (and tries to reverse), it fails with the same error. It doesn't matter if I the fixture or not.

Controller:

```
  var newHistoryItem = this.store.createRecord('history-item', {
    question: question,
    answer: answer
  });
  newHistoryItem.save().then(success).catch(failure);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think using `toArray` is fine, no need to reinvent the wheel. Even Ember's enumerable/array methods are implemented using `toArray` under the hood.

I like keeping transforms on controllers/components, so Routes are only concerned with [URL -> data] logic. I think here I would keep the model hook returning the server data, and use a computed property on the controller:

```
import Ember from 'ember';

export default Ember.Controller.extend({

  reversedItems: Ember.computed('model.[]', function() {
    return this.get('model').toArray().reverse();
  })
});
```

Twiddle: https://ember-twiddle.com/6527ef6d5f617449b8780148e7afe595?openFiles=controllers.application.js%2C

You could also use the `reverse` helper from [Ember Composable Helpers](https://github.com/DockYard/ember-composable-helpers#reverse) and do it in the template:

```
{{#each (reverse model) as |item|}}
  ...
{{/each}}
```

Comment: `reverseObjects()` supposed to be work. but its not working. is this expected behavior or do you find any reasoning for this?.

Comment: In model hook when you do `this.store.findAll('history-item').then(function(items){ return items.reverseObjects(); })`  its throwing `TypeError: internalModel.getRecord coming from record-array.js` ..i tried in your twiddle too.

Comment: Do it in the controller, after calling `toArray`. Can't do it directly on resolved promise value bc it's not an array.

Comment: Do you happen to know why you can't do the RecordArray's reverseObjects() API call on the promise that resolves to an RecordArray's type? When I print out model property in the template, it shows RecordArray as the resolved promise

Maybe I'm not fully understanding of how promises work. Will the controller only see it as a promise vs a concrete record array? Thank you so much for responding to my question. I've been searching all over the internet for a coherent response about this.

Comment: @samselikoff Oh my, this might be the answer after all. Is this consistent with your understanding?

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15102668/manipulating-a-recordarray

Comment: More or less yes. Ember's view/templating layer has some magic parts...it understands how to iterate over objects that aren't really arrays. It's best to do transforms like sorting/filtering on controllers/components via CPs.

Answer (score 4):

The result returned from `store.findAll` and `store.query` is an AdapterPopulatedRecordArray (live array), mutation methods like `addObject,addObjects,removeObject,removeObjects,
unshiftObject,unshiftObjects,pushObject,pushObjects,reverseObjects,setObjects,shiftObject,clear,popObject,removeAt,removeObject,removeObjects,insertAt` should not be used.

Have a look at corresponding [discussion](https://github.com/emberjs/data/issues/3530) and 
[Proposed PR](https://github.com/emberjs/data/commit/37aa871d33afb25d8803520aa9a14677c523acba) to throw error and suggestions to use toArray() to copy array instead of mutating.

Comment: Thank you for your answer! This is the conclusion I've come to after trawling google for hours and hours. I should have looked at the github earlier.

Comment: I've found that, at least for a mirage backed server, findAll() returns just a RecordArray rather than AdapterPopulatedRecordArray. The proposed PR you linked seems to be stale but someone else merged in a change for the AdapterPopulatedRecordArray after that discussion. It fixes the issue for store.query calls but not for findAll().

Comment: As stated in the linked discussion, store.query() returns a non-live array while store.filter() and store.findAll() return FilteredRecordArray and RecordArray, respectively. Both of these are live arrays. Either way, it seems the RecordArrays should not be muttable but only FilteredRecordArray and AdapterPopulatedRecordArray are protected with a good error message.

Comment: I've added PR to fix this. Anyone knows anyone that can help bump this, that would great! I'd like to settle this or at least find out if my thoughts are right or wrong.

https://github.com/emberjs/data/pull/4520